# How to retrieve the next CompletableFuture from a List?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Suppose you are forced to implement this interface:

```
public void process(List<CompletableFuture<T>> futures);
```

Suppose you want to further process each item, sequentially.

What is the most efficient, with the least code, way to begin processing each `CompletableFuture<T>` in the current thread as soon as it completes?

Is this the best that can be done? It is too verbose and not very efficient, and doesn't scale very much at all:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(futures.size()); // yikes
CompletionService<T> queue = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(pool);
// pseudo-code: try-catch omitted for clarity
futures.forEach(future -> queue.submit(() -> future.get()));
for(int i=0; i < futures.size(); ++i) { 
    T item = queue.take();
    ... process ...
}
```

Comment: tags fixed ....

Comment: "not very efficient, and doesn't scale very much at all" Because it is sequential.

Comment: It doesn't scale not because it's sequential, but because it creates a thread for each item to wait for its completion. The sequential process itself is not a bottleneck.